# write pyspark Rdd or DF in neo4j

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j, pyspark, rdd

I'm experiencing some issue with py2neo and spark-driver since i could not insert node inside a foreach loop or map loop .Like the code below for exemple.

```
from py2neo import authenticate, Graph, cypher, Node
from pyspark import broadcast
infos=df.rdd

authenticate("localhost:7474", "neo4j", "admin")
graph = Graph(password='admin')
tx = graph.begin()

def node(row):
    query = Node("item", event_id=row[0], text=row[19])
    tx.create(query)



infos.foreach(node)
tx.commit()
```

here is the end of the stack trace :

```
/usr/local/apache/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/rdd.py in _wrap_function(sc, func, deserializer, serializer, profiler)
   2386     assert serializer, "serializer should not be empty"
   2387     command = (func, profiler, deserializer, serializer)
-> 2388     pickled_command, broadcast_vars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
   2389     return sc._jvm.PythonFunction(bytearray(pickled_command), env, includes, sc.pythonExec,
   2390                                   sc.pythonVer, broadcast_vars, sc._javaAccumulator)

/usr/local/apache/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/rdd.py in _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
   2372     # the serialized command will be compressed by broadcast
   2373     ser = CloudPickleSerializer()
-> 2374     pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)
   2375     if len(pickled_command) > (1 << 20):  # 1M
   2376         # The broadcast will have same life cycle as created PythonRDD

/usr/local/apache/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/serializers.py in dumps(self, obj)
    462 
    463     def dumps(self, obj):
--> 464         return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, 2)
    465 
    466 

/usr/local/apache/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py in dumps(obj, protocol)
    702 
    703     cp = CloudPickler(file,protocol
```

I think i can't pass the parameter tx inside the loop.
We try to overpass this issue by instanciating a connection directly inside the loop like the code bellow . It works for small matrix but when i try with a 20 million row one it stop at some point

```
from py2neo import authenticate, Graph, cypher, Node
infos=df.rdd
authenticate("localhost:7474", "neo4j", "password")


def node(row):
    graph = Graph(password='admin')
    tx = graph.begin()
    query = Node("item", event_id=row[0], text=row[19])
    tx.create(query)
    tx.commit()

infos.foreach(node)
```

I made some research about the neo4j-spark connector it seems that you could add the library but there is no example provided and i'm not sure at all that such functionnality are actually provided in python. What would be the best way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

A standard pattern to resolve this type of issues is to use `foreachPartition`:

```
def nodes(rows):
    graph = Graph(password='admin')
    tx = graph.begin()
    for row in rows:
        query = Node("item", event_id=row[0], text=row[19])
        tx.create(query)
    tx.commit()

infos.foreachPartition(nodes)
```

Comment: it seems to work for 10000 but for  bigger one i get py2neo.database.status.GraphError: HTTP GET returned response 429